# trying to make a timer stop when the user reaches the bottom of the page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, timer, scroll

I have a timer that starts counting up when the page is loaded.  I want it to stop when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page.  Here is the jQuery I've written:

```
function timerTick(time, stop)
{
    if(stop == false)
    {
        setInterval(function () 
        {
            time += 1;
            var displayTime = time/10;
            if(displayTime % 1 != 0)
            {
                $('.time').text(displayTime.toString());
            }
            else
            {
                $('.time').text(displayTime.toString() + ".0");
            } 

        }, 100);
    }
    else //behavior is the same if i remove the else block
    {
        return;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var time = 0;
    var stop = false;

    timerTick(time, stop);

    //check if we're at the bottom
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            stop = true;
        }
    });


});
```

The timer counts up perfectly, the problem is I can't get it to stop.  If I replace the `stop = true;` line with `alert('abc');`, the alert shows up when the user reaches the bottom.  So all of the pieces are working, just for some reason setting stop to true doesn't stop the timerTick function from going into the `if(stop == false)` block.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

---

**Edit:** I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C3PtT/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear interval as soos as user reach the end of page. Otherwise it will continue executing.

Try:

```
var intervalId;

    function timerTick(time, stop)
    {
        if(stop == false)
        {
            intervalId=setInterval(function () //Set the interval in a var
            {
                time += 1;
                var displayTime = time/10;
                if(displayTime % 1 != 0)
                {
                    $('.time').text(displayTime.toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    $('.time').text(displayTime.toString() + ".0");
                } 

            }, 100);
        }
        else //behavior is the same if i remove the else block
        {

            return;
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var time = 0;
        var stop = false;

        timerTick(time, stop);

        //check if we're at the bottom
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                stop = true;
                clearInterval(intervalId);//HERE clear the interval
            }
        });


    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C3PtT/1/)

Answer (score 0):

to determine bottom of the page you could try this

```
if(window.innerHeight + document.body.scrollTop >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    stop = true;
}
```

Update:
you need to make your variable `stop` global, declare it outside of `documnet.ready` function.

Comment: Like I said, if I use an alert instead of setting stop to true, the alert comes up at the bottom of the page.  So what I have works fine in that regard.  Also, just tested it for the goof and it also did not work.

Comment: why would it need to be global? I'm passing it in as a parameter.  (Honest question, not being a smart ass)

Comment: Cause when `scroll` fires it's not from inside `document.ready`, and in JS variables are function scoped.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` function returns number that you can later pass into `clearInterval` to stop the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Declare

```
var Timeout=0;
```

check

```
 if(stop == false)
```

inside the setInterval function

like

```
  Timeout=setInterval(function () 
    {

       if(stop == false) 
            {
        time += 1;
        var displayTime = time/10;
        if(displayTime % 1 != 0)
        {
            $('.time').text(displayTime.toString());
        }
        else
        {
            $('.time').text(displayTime.toString() + ".0");
        } 
             }
       else

             {
            clearInterval(Timeout);
             }

    }, 100);
```